# What is the best way to get integer's negative sign and store it as char?

Tags: c, char, int, negative-number

How to get an integer's sign and store it in a char? One way is:

```
int n = -5
char c;
if(n<0)
    c = '-';
else
    c = '+';
```

Or:

```
char c = n < 0 ? '-' : '+';
```

But is there a way to do it without conditionals?

Comment: You mean something like `char c = (n<0)? '-' : '+';`?

Comment: @Blaze That should be an answer.

Comment: @Blaze That's identical to what the OP has, just less readable.

Comment: There is no way. Even Blaze's suggestion involves an `if` (involves a condition check).

Comment: That is similar what I am doing. Actualy I am looking for answer if it is posible to do it without if statment or conditional operator.

Comment: @NikosC. I didn't put it as an answer because I don't know what OP is trying to accomplish. Turns out he doesn't want a ternary conditional either.

Comment: What should the char's value be if the integer is not negative?

Comment: Sorry, @ Nikos C.  it should be `+`. Code updated

Comment: "is there a way to do it without conditionals?" is not a good coding goal.  Better to code for clarity. `char c = n < 0 ? '-' : '+';` is fine.  Perhaps terse code such as `char c = "+-"[n < 0];`

Comment: @chux `char c = "-+"[(n >> 31)+1];` Logical shift sets `c` to `\0`. For maximum portability you'd do `"-+-"` but this is some seriously obscure code :)

Comment: @Lundin Yes `"-+"[(n >> 31)+1]` is amiss, yet clarity vs. obscurity is not of part of OP's goal.  `char c = n < 0 ? '-' : '+';` would be clear enough, yet OP wants "without conditionals" - for un-posted reasons.  If one is looking for constant time emitted code, one must be careful as C does not oblige seemingly constant time source code to emit constant time machine code.  IMO, "best way to get integer's negative sign and store it as char" and "without conditionals" are contradictory goals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the most efficient and portable way, but it doesn't win any beauty awards.

We can assume that the MSB of a signed integer is always set if it is negative. This is a 100% portable assumption even when taking exotic signedness formats in account (one's complement, signed magnitude). Therefore the fastest way is to simply mask out the MSB from the integer.

The MSB of any integer is found at location `CHAR_BIT * sizeof(n) - 1;`. On a typical 32 bit mainstream system, this would for example be `8 * 4 - 1` = 31.

So we can write a function like this:

```
_Bool is_signed (int n)
{
  const unsigned int sign_bit_n = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(n) - 1;
  return (_Bool) ((unsigned int)n >> sign_bit_n);
}
```

On x86-64 gcc 9.1 (-O3), this results in very efficient code:

```
is_signed:
        mov     eax, edi
        shr     eax, 31
        ret
```

The advantage of this method is also that, unlike code such as `x < 0`, it won't risk getting translated into "branch if negative" instructions when ported.

Complete example:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>

_Bool is_signed (int n)
{
  const unsigned int sign_bit_n = CHAR_BIT * sizeof(n) - 1;
  return (_Bool) ((unsigned int)n >> sign_bit_n);
}

int main (void)
{
  int n = -1;

  const char SIGNS[] = {' ', '-'};
  char sign = SIGNS[is_signed(n)];
  putchar(sign);
}
```

Disassembly (x86-64 gcc 9.1 (-O3)):

```
is_signed:
        mov     eax, edi
        shr     eax, 31
        ret
main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     rsi, QWORD PTR stdout[rip]
        mov     edi, 45
        call    _IO_putc
        xor     eax, eax
        add     rsp, 8
        ret
```

Comment: How I understand `uint32_t` is equal respectively to `unsigned_int`. Is that right?

Comment: @ph7 The type of the local variable in the function isn't really relevant here, it could be any integer type. I just typed uint32_t out of habit, but it has no relevance to the outcome of the code. The `1u` - which is of type unsigned int, is what matters.

Comment: I suppose you [took a look at what the compiler does](https://godbolt.org/z/2XyRIi) and then reversed it to C code? :-)

Comment: "it won't risk getting translated into "branch if negative" instructions when ported." --> Instead the conversion of an `unsigned` to a `bool`risks getting translated into a "branch if (non) zero" when ported.

Comment: @chux I considered that, but since optimizations are already done at the point of conversion, I don't think it is necessary. One can probably reduce the risk by right shifting instead though, will update the answer.

Comment: `(unsigned int)n >> sign_bit_n` is better - had no modern porting concerns.  It does negate the need for narrowing done by `(_Bool)`.

Comment: @chux Yeah at least I hope so, if the compiler realizes it can just copy the LS byte. When I tried both versions they resulted in the same machine code on x86, ARM and PowerPC though.

Answer (score 5):

This creates branchless code with gcc/clang on x86-64:

```
void storeneg(int X, char *C)
{
    *C='+';
    *C += (X<0)*('-'-'+');
}
```

https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/yua1go

Comment: X<0 doesn't necessarily give branchless code though. I would expect it to translate to "branch if negative" on a lot of architectures.

Comment: @Lundin Added "on x86-64". The C side at least is certainly without an `if` or a `?:`.

Comment: Yeah but most of the C operators with a boolean result tend to get translated to branches (in particular the `&&` and `||`). I posted an uglier but possibly more portable version.

Answer (score 1):

```
char c = 43 + signbit(n) * 2 ;
```

- `char 43` is `'+'`
- `char 45` is `'-'`
- signbit(NEGATIVE INTEGER) is `true`, converted to `1`

`int signbit(int)` is included in [`cmath` in C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/signbit) and [`math.h` in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/signbit)

Comment: I am using C and that trows me error `fatal error: cmath: No such file or directory #include <cmath>`

Comment: maybe in C, you need math.h, https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/signbit 
But by document c's signbit only promise nonzero value instead of true or 1

Comment: Is `signbit` guaranteed to work for integers in C? Nothing in the standard seems to guarantee this, it just says that it is a macro of the pseudo-code form `int signbit(real-floating x);`. C++ is another story, because it uses overloaded functions instead of a macro, but this is tagged C.

Comment: Looking at C libs implementation of `signbit`, it seems to always enforce a promotion to floating point. Newer versions of gcc refuse to even compile it. So... this is not a good idea.